# Home made popsicles sticking to mold

Tags: dessert, frozen

We had some great organic popsicles made from pineapple. They were a bit pricey so we decided to make some ourselves. The problem is that we can't get them to release from the plastic molds very well. Other than running them under hot water, is there a trick we can use to get these things to release a little easier?

Comment: Can't you just twist the container like you do with an ice tray

Comment: I think the hot water should be enough; dip quickly in a bath of very hot  water and quickly release from the mold and put back in the freezer ASAP.

Comment: Try cleaning the plastic molds with a magic eraser.  There could be very fine surface damage to the plastic that could be smoothed out.

Answer (score 3):

Try silicone molds, I use them for ice cubes and they are *much* easier to release ice from than plastic trays.